# get multidimensional results from mysql/php via ajax

Tags: mysql, json, ajax, encode

[Putting mySQL Database Information into a JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322705/putting-mysql-database-information-into-a-javascript-array)

I'm trying to use the above example of passing MYSQL data to AJAX but it only uses a single dimensional array, how do I get data from a multidimensional array?

Here are some test code that I've tried (load_ajax.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","database_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$i=0; 
$arraylist=""; // Initialise local array for icons
$result = $mysqli->query('select * from word_table');

while($row=$result ->fetch_object()) {               
    $arraylist[$i]["word_id"]=$row->word_id;
    $arraylist[$i]["word_name"]=$row->word_name;
    $i++;  
}

//convert the PHP array into JSON format, so it works with javascript
echo json_encode($arraylist);
?>
```

And in HTML (load_ajax.html):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "load_ajax.php",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            alert(data[i]["word_id"]+"/"+data[i]["word_name"]);     
        }
    }
});
```

The above code will not work for me.  Previously I only used PHP to generate my array and print straight out to HTML.  Now I want to use AJAX to load MySQL data from PHP into a javascript multidimensional array that can be used more interactively with other local functions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code on a different browser (Firefox) and it works no problem.

I have no idea why it won't work in Chrome.  Reloading the page will not let it work again. Had to close the window and try again.

It's working sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "load_ajax.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
               data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
               $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                 alert(data[i].word_id +"/" +data[i].word_name);
               });​
             }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery's  `$.each()` inside ajax function.The `each()` method specifies a function to run for each matched element.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "load_ajax.php",
    datatype:"json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    $.each(data, function(index,element){
                        alert(element.word_id);
                        alert(element.word_name);
                    });

                }
    });
```

For more clear see fiddle here...http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBKCNOC7O3B8